# Low speed in project different to API25

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have a low speed problem on devices with APIs differents to 25 and I do not know how to fix it. I am currently working in an application that connects to a remote database and reads data from a webservice and then displays it on the screen. This is a simple example of the main menu of the application:

```
public class PrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView img_citas;
String cod_persona;
String nom;
String fecha_actual=String.valueOf(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", new java.util.Date()));


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);


    img_citas = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_citas);

    cod_persona = 9;
    nom = "fisios";

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ObtDatos();

}

public void ObtDatos(){

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String url = "http://192.168.0.252:62/datos/policlinica/webservices/nombre_fisio.php?COD_PERSONA="+cod_persona;


    client.post(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

            if (statusCode==200){ 
                nom = obtCodigo(new String(responseBody)); 

                if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {     

                    if (!nom.equals("")) {  
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(nom);
                        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(fecha_actual);

                    } else {
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Policlínica");
                    }
                }

                img_citas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(PrincipalActivity.this, HorariosActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });

}

public String obtCodigo(String response){ 

    String cod_usu="";

    try{
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);

        if (json.length()>0){   

            cod_usu = json.getJSONObject(0).getString("NOMBRE");
             }else{

            cod_usu="";
        }


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }

    return cod_usu;
}
}
```

Basically, it's read the name of a person in a remote database and place it in the toolbar. Something that should not take more than 2 seconds, but it takes me until 9 seconds!

Just in case, I also attach the contents of the gradle file, in case the problem comes through:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cristobal.policlinica"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The application works well, but only on mobile devices with API 25 (Android 7). The rest, for example API 23 (Android 6) or API 28 (Android 8), although it reads well from the database and shows them, it does it at very low speed. The previous code, which is very simple, takes almost 9 seconds to read it completely and display it on the screen. While with API 25 it is practically instantaneous.

I'm sure something escapes me, but I think I'm too newbie to see the problem.

Any advice on what is happening to me?

EDIT:

This is the logCat of a device where everything works fine:

```
06-14 09:43:25.837 6965-7103/com.example.cristobal.policlinica D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
06-14 09:43:26.333 6965-6976/com.example.cristobal.policlinica I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4305(281KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 24MB/24MB, paused 7.051ms total 50.743ms
06-14 09:43:26.462 6965-6976/com.example.cristobal.policlinica I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 568(30KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 13% free, 24MB/28MB, paused 5.509ms total 117.376ms
06-14 09:43:27.303 6965-6972/com.example.cristobal.policlinica W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.837ms
06-14 09:43:27.654 6965-6965/com.example.cristobal.policlinica V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 72 from 72 (100%)
```

And this one is the logcat of a device that takes a long time:

```
06-14 10:04:24.916 3086-3347/com.example.cristobal.policlinica D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
06-14 10:04:25.973 3086-3097/com.example.cristobal.policlinica W/art: Suspending all threads took: 95.884ms
06-14 10:04:26.009 3086-3093/com.example.cristobal.policlinica W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.145ms
06-14 10:04:26.016 3086-3364/com.example.cristobal.policlinica W/art: Verification of java.lang.String cz.msebera.android.httpclient.protocol.DefaultedHttpContext.toString() took 143.593ms
06-14 10:04:26.016 3086-3097/com.example.cristobal.policlinica I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5085(329KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 29% free, 9MB/13MB, paused 106.940ms total 471.003ms
06-14 10:04:26.414 3086-3093/com.example.cristobal.policlinica W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.969ms
06-14 10:04:31.861 3086-3086/com.example.cristobal.policlinica V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 72 from 72 (100%)
```

These 3 lines...

```
06-14 10:04:25.973 3086-3097/com.example.cristobal.policlinica W/art: Suspending all threads took: 95.884ms
06-14 10:04:26.009 3086-3093/com.example.cristobal.policlinica W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.145ms
06-14 10:04:26.016 3086-3364/com.example.cristobal.policlinica W/art: Verification of java.lang.String cz.msebera.android.httpclient.protocol.DefaultedHttpContext.toString() took 143.593ms
```

...are different and I think they are causing the slow mode, but I do not know how to fix it.

Some advice? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is an app issue and not a server problem? Have you been able to figure out what is slow? If it's the request it's probably because there is a connection issue with your server and because your server is slow for whatever reason?

Comment: Sure, the problem is with the connections to the database. That is what slows down the application. Currently the database is uploaded to a server for testing. The strange thing is that on a device with Android 7.0 (Api 25), the application works very well. Very fast. But only with Android 7.0, with the rest (6.0, 5.0...), the database reading is very, very slow. Works, but slow.

Comment: Then you need to check the server. Doesn't seem to be an app related issue, to me

Comment: I have bought the logcat on several devices, and I see the different lines (I edit the main thread to show them), but I do not understand its meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

In the end I replaced the library loopj by Volley and mysteriously it worked perfectly.
I do not know the reason. I guess I would not be doing the requests well, but with Volley I managed to make it work on all devices.

Thanks!